# How to use the value obtained in POST method outside the function

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Below is my directory structure:

```
/home
 |___ /sub_directory
           |__abc.py
 |__ xyz.py
```

Below is my xyz.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for,send_from_directory, jsonify, render_template
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

app = Flask(__name__)

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',database='test',user='root',password='')

    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select id,name from skill_category;")
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        out = [item for t in record for item in t]
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL",e)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def dropdown():
    val = record
    return render_template('Rankcv.html', val = val)

@app.route('/get-subskills', methods=['POST'])
def get_subskills():
    skills = request.form['select_skills']
    cursor.execute("SELECT skill_items.name FROM skill_items WHERE skill_items.category_id = " + skills + " ;")
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    out = [item for t in record for item in t]
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
    return jsonify(something)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now I have to use the value of variable out and skills in abc.py.

I tried importing xyz directly and tried to retrieve the value using function name (get_subskills), but it didnt work. Can someone please explain how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to access `xyz.py` from `__abc.py` and calling the function `get_subskills` and trying to get the stringified value?

Comment: Yes. @SundeepPidugu

Comment: Do you have an error while you are running? Please post

Comment: What do you have in abc.py? What are you trying to do? Does abc.py have any flask code? Importing xyz into abc is really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Import the `abc` function into `xyz`.